# Reference Coordinates column in dataframe 1 to fill origin and destination coordinates in dataframe 2

Tags: r

Data Frame 1(aircode) has a column called Coordinates and Ident. (Reference Data Frame)
Data Frame 2(data) has a column called Origin and a column called Destination. (Master Data Frame)

I would like to add 2 more columns to Data Frame 2 called Origin_coordinates and Destination_coordinates.

Ident contains airport IATA codes and so does Origin and Destination. I was thinking of using some sort of Vlookup function so they can reference each other. Then I can extract the appropriate airports Coordinates for Origin and Destination and apply them to the new columns

I only know how to merge the data frames, but that doesn't do what I want.

```
Merged=merge(data, aircode, by.x="Origin", by.y="ident", all.x = TRUE)
```

If you would like the actual files, take a look [here](https://github.com/RehanDaya/STA380/tree/master/exercises) (ABIA.csv) for dataframe 2 and [here](https://datahub.io/core/airport-codes) (airport-codes) for dataframe 1

Comment: Add a small reproducible example using `dput` and show expected output for the same. Read here on how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

# read data
data <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RehanDaya/STA380/master/data/ABIA.csv")
aircode <- fread("https://datahub.io/core/airport-codes/r/airport-codes.csv")

# get unique values for "vlookup"
d <- unique(data[, .(Origin, Dest)])
ac <- unique(aircode[, .(ident, name)])

# Function to map values
find_name <- function(orig, dest) {
    .orig <- ac[ident %like% orig]$name[1]
    .dest <- ac[ident %like% dest]$name[1]
    return(list(Origin.Name = .orig, Dest.Name = .dest))
}

# Create two new columns for name
d[, c("Origin.Name", "Dest.Name") := find_name(Origin, Dest), by = .I]

# print result
head(d, 5)
#    Origin Dest                     Origin.Name                                Dest.Name
# 1:    MEM  AUS   Memphis International Airport          Austin Robert Mueller Municipal
# 2:    AUS  ORD Austin Robert Mueller Municipal     Chicago O'Hare International Airport
# 3:    AUS  PHX Austin Robert Mueller Municipal Phoenix Sky Harbor International Airport
# 4:    AUS  MEM Austin Robert Mueller Municipal            Memphis International Airport
# 5:    AUS  DFW Austin Robert Mueller Municipal         WÃƒÂ¼rzburg-Schenkenturm Airport
```

This could also be done without defining a separate function (like the find_name function in my previous example) by updating the data.table by reference:

```
library(data.table)

# read data
data <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RehanDaya/STA380/master/data/ABIA.csv")
aircode <- fread("https://datahub.io/core/airport-codes/r/airport-codes.csv")

# get unique values for "vlookup"
d <- unique(data[, .(Origin, Dest)])
ac <- unique(aircode[, .(ident, name)])

# Create two new columns for name
d[, `:=` (
    Origin.Name = ac[ident %like% Origin]$name[1], 
    Dest.Name = ac[ident %like% Dest]$name[1]
  ), 
  by = .(Origin, Dest)]

# print result
head(d, 5)
#    Origin Dest                     Origin.Name                                Dest.Name
# 1:    MEM  AUS   Memphis International Airport          Austin Robert Mueller Municipal
# 2:    AUS  ORD Austin Robert Mueller Municipal     Chicago O'Hare International Airport
# 3:    AUS  PHX Austin Robert Mueller Municipal Phoenix Sky Harbor International Airport
# 4:    AUS  MEM Austin Robert Mueller Municipal            Memphis International Airport
# 5:    AUS  DFW Austin Robert Mueller Municipal         WÃƒÂ¼rzburg-Schenkenturm Airport
```

Comment: Copy the first few rows of output to show in the answer as text. Don't add screenshots.